# ServiceWorker not intercepting URLs

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm trying to get a serviceWorker to intercept some of my URLs. At this point, I only want the SW to log that it's doing something.

I get console logs saying that the SW correctly initializes, but the `fetch` listener is never called.

Things I've tried so far:

- Make sure that webpack doesn't modify the source of my SW (fetching the JS file manually returns the unminified version without any changes).
- Use `fetch` to retrieve my JSON payload.
- Use the Chrome devtools to update my SW on reload (still doesn't work after several reloads).
- If I omit the scope, the SW will then intercept all requests, but I only want to intercept requests to `/boot/app/3/`.

I register my SW with:

```
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator)
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw-boot.js', {
      scope: '/boot/app/3/'
    });
```

And the code of the SW is:

```
const CACHE = 'boot';

console.log('sw-boot.js');

self.addEventListener('activate', function () {
  clients.claim();
  console.log('Now ready to handle fetches!');
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (evt) {
  console.log('The service worker is serving the asset.');

  evt.respondWith(fromNetwork(evt.request, 400).catch(function () {
    return fromCache(evt.request);
  }));
});

function fromNetwork(request, timeout) {
  console.log('fromNetwork');
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {

    var timeoutId = setTimeout(reject, timeout);

    fetch(request).then(function (response) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      fulfill(response);
    }, reject);
  });
}

function fromCache(request) {
  console.log('fromCache');
  return caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
    return cache.match(request).then(function (matching) {
      return matching || Promise.reject('no-match');
    });
  });
}
```

I then fetch my URLs with:

```
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator)
    return fetch(bootUrl, {credentials: 'same-origin'})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        $rootScope.$evalAsync(() => {
          self.update(json);
          done();
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i can judge is that your configuration of service worker will only intercept requests which are initiated from pages which follow the url pattern `/boot/app/3/` for e.g. if you have a page `http://localhost:8080/boot/app/3/index.html` and this page loads some assets then the network requests for these assets will be intercepted by service worker otherwise if you have a like `http://localhost:8080/index.html` then service worker will not able to  intercept requests because of the scope which you have used during its registration

Comment: Unless you're serving service worker from webpack static files, then you can add additional options to `static` configuration: 
`staticOptions: {
                    setHeaders: (res, path, stat) => {
                       // check if it's path to your worker
                        if (path === 'mockServiceWorker.js') {
                            res.set('Service-Worker-Allowed', '/');
                        }
                    },
                },
`